# Function triggered only once by a FileType event for the current buffer?

Tags: vim

So I can do this: Assign a keymap that is only active in the current buffer upon triggering the FileType event for that buffer. The actual assignment happens only once, the keymap stays active only in that specific buffer.

```
autocmd FileType javascript nmap <buffer> <leader>3 <Plug>BananaTest
```

But why I can't do this?

```
autocmd FileType javascript call s:ExecuteHook('ft==javascript triggered.')
```

Is there a way to call a function the first time a buffer gets assigned a FileType of `javascript`? So only once, exiting and entering that buffer will not trigger the call again.

I would like to add that I'm trying to make this work without implementing a `/ftplugin/javascript/javascript.vim` kind of a solution.

Comment: `autocmd FileType javascript call ExecuteHook('BufEnter')`?

Comment: Sorry, my example was misleading (I edited it to clarify), I don't want this to be a Buffer related event, just called once, for the buffer as `set ft=javascript` is being executed. So only once per buffer.

Comment: There are only two buffer events that are guaranteed to occur exactly once per buffer lifetime, i.e. creation and deletion (wiping). Your question is still misleading and not understandable.

Comment: It is exactly what a function call would do inside a `/ftplugin/javascript/javascript.vim` file. So triggered only once when the `ft` is being set to `javascript`. I was just trying to avoid adding that workflow and was wondering if it is possible to do this with only a small addition to my `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--- EDIT ---

After you clarified your intent…

```
autocmd FileType javascript call Foo()
```

is the proper autocommand for calling `Foo()` when the filetype of a buffer is set to `javascript`.

That said, the recommendation below to move your filetype-specific stuff to a proper filetype plugin still stands. In this case:

```
" in after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
function! Foo()
    echo 'Hello from a JS file!'
endfunction
call Foo()
nmap <buffer> <leader>3 <Plug>BananaTest
```

--- ENDEDIT ---

The `:help FileType` event is only triggered once in the lifecycle of a buffer: during its creation, when its filetype has been set.

If you want something to happen every time you enter a buffer with a given filetype, the proper event is, get ready, `:help BufEnter`:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype =~ 'javascript' | do something | endif
```

Where we have…

- a `BufEnter` autocommand,
- that is triggered for every buffer,
- that does something only if that buffer has a `filetype` containing `javascript`.

But littering your `vimrc` with filetype-specific stuff is messy. Instead, create `after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` if it doesn't already exist and define your filetype-specific functions, mappings, and commands there.

It should look something like this:

```
" in after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
nmap <buffer> <key> ...
augroup JavaScript
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter <buffer> ...
augroup END
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this set up in a way that it fires up the first time a `FileType javascript` event is triggered for a buffer, then going into and out of that buffer should not trigger it again.

Comment: Well, that's not what you asked.

Comment: But your solution worked, after your edit. The `call Foo()` is triggered only once, when the file is being read. So if I read in `file1.js`,  `call Foo()` is triggered. Then I load `file2.js` and `call Foo()` is triggered again. But switching between the two files in *not* triggering `call Foo()`, which is the logic I needed. This was also suggested by @r_31415

Comment: My initial solution worked before you reworded your question, too. FWIW, your language is confusing: "filetype is set", "read", and "enter" are all very specific and *different* points in the lifecycle of a buffer. I suggest you think long and hard about your wording next time, so that people don't waste their time on non-existing problems.

Comment: Well, I think it is a nice question/answer combination. Further clarification hopefully should help others, don't think any time has been wasted here.